# Stacked/overlapping UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, overlap

Please consider the attached image.
What I want to achieve, is alternating UITableVieCells, of which the content is larger than the cell itself.
As a result, I can use the screen real estate in a more efficient way.
I think I will be able to place the image differently depending on the odd or even cell. 
What I'm specifically interested in, is setting the .contentview.height larger than the height of the cell itself.
Quite likely, i'm stuck with a solution direction, while a different approach would be more feasible. I would love to hear about that.

[image]

Comment: Try setting the `estimatedRowHeight` property on the table view.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: The question is twofold: a) how do I solve this problem, and b) assuming that I'm on the right track, how do I adjust the height of the content view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the content view via `cell.contentView` and set the `frame` directly.

But I personally wouldn't touch it because it might be managed by the cell.

What I would do are:

1. Make the cells and their content views background transparent.

   ```
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   ```
2. Set the cells and the content views `clipsToBounds` to `NO`.

   ```
   cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
   cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;
   ```
3. Alternatively position the `UIImageView` to the left or the right in the content view.

   ```
   if (indexPath.row % 2) {
       imageView.frame = /* set to the left */
   } else {
       imageView.frame = /* set to the right */
   }
   [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
   ```

Sure, if you want to be able to tapped on the image view to do something, this will break. Unless you add some hit testing code. Alternatively, you can use `UICollectionView` and create a custom layout, which in my opinion, is a better way to go.